# Can somebody explain how numpy.where and True/False works?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and numpy. I have written code to teach myself. However, I cannot comprehend how the below code produces its result.

Input

```
np.where([[True, False], [True, True]], 
         [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[9, 8], [7, 6]])
```

Output

```
array([[1, 8],
       [3, 4]])
```

I do not understand how this result is achieved.

Comment: You apply np.where in a list that contains 3 sublists. Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: `help(np.where)` will explain that this takes elements from x (`[[1,2],[3,4]`) where condition is `True`, and elements from y elsewhere, in this case, the `False` condition is returning the `8` value from `y`.

Comment: this is literally the example from the `help` dox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a combination of broadcasting and the function of the where conditional. In the numpy.where docstring it states:

> Parameters: 
>   condition : array_like, bool
>   Where True, yield x, otherwise yield y.

In your case your boolean input is (2, 2), and is followed by two arrays of shape (2, 2).

It applies:

```
[True False] 
[True True ]
```

to x:

```
[1, 8]
[3, 4]
```

resulting in:

```
[1, _]
[3, 4]
```

and since the second element is false takes from the second input y:

```
[9, 8]
[7, 6]
```

resulting in:

```
[_, 8]
[_, _]
```

Then combines to get the output you see.

Comment: Thank you. I had read the documentation. Like David Zemens the example is from there I just could not understand the logic behind this specific example. Your explanation. Cleared it up.